# Insert JSON array in mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, json

In a mysql table "section", I have 5 columns (1 int, 1 text and 3 json arrays). The JSON array values are present as variables 's', 'l' and 't'. I am unable to insert values in the table. My code is as follows:

```
mycursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE section (tid int, text text, spots json, spotl json, terms json)""")
s = json.dumps(["s1", "s2 s3"], ensure_ascii=False)
l = json.dumps(["L1", "L2"], ensure_ascii=False)
t = json.dumps(["t1", "t2"], ensure_ascii=False)
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO section (tid, text, spots, spotl, terms) VALUES ('101', 'pageview', ?, ?, ?)""", (s, l, t),)
print(mycursor.rowcount, " record inserted")
mycursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM section""")
x = mycursor.fetchall()
sp = x[0][2]
print(type(sp))
```

The error is: "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement" for the line: "    mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO section (tid, text, spots, spotl, terms) VALUES ('101', 'pageview', ?, ?, ?)""", (s, l, t),)". Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using %s instead of ?

Comment: You should probably combine your s, l and t JSONs inside a higher level JSON element and insert that to MySQL table.

Comment: @topher: Yes, I tried and it is working. But, I am unable to extract these columns (spots, spotl, terms) as json arrays when using """SELECT * FROM section""".

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer, try this:

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO section (tid, text, spots, spotl, terms) VALUES ('101', 'pageview', %s, %s, %s)""", (s, l, t))
```

you are not able to extract column because by looking at your code, you haven't commited the query.After mycursor.execute(Insert) write **commit** statement.